# C# class inheritance and polymorphism with polymorphic fields

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm running into an occasional design issue with classes, mostly in some video game stuff. The problem arises when a class that extends another class (such as a `Player`) has a field that is also a class that has its own extended classes. I know this is a pattern issue but not sure how to resolve it properly.

Let's take a super simple example.

1. A class called Engine that drives
2. A class called SpecialEngine that charges
3. A class called Car with an Engine
4. A class called SpecialCar with a SpecialEngine

```cs
public class Engine {
  public void Drive() {}
}

public class SpecialEngine : Engine {
  public void Charge() {}
}

public class Car {
  protected Engine engine;
  public virtual void Move() {
    this.engine.Drive();
  }
}

public class SpecialCar : Car {
  // Both SpecialCar.engine and SpecialCar.specialEngine 
  // would need to be set to an instance of SpecialEngine
  private SpecialEngine specialEngine;
  public override void Move() {
    // or.. cast this.engine to SpecialEngine? 
    this.specialEngine.Charge();
    base.Move();
  }
}
```

`Car` has an `Engine`, and you can pass a `SpecialEngine` to `Car` (idk if C# uses the term "slicing" but this at least works in C++). But you cannot access any properties of `SpecialEngine`. So you make `SpecialCar` that could accept a `SpecialEngine` as its `engine` but you want to access `SpecialEngine`, so you make a second field called `specialEngine` and now have two references to it?

My thinking here is wrong and I'm not sure what I should do. I know I could have maybe a generic `Car<T>` but I feel like I may end up with `Car<A, B, C, D...>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# supports [Covariant returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns). Just can use a single `SpecialEngine` in `SpecialCar`.

```
public class Engine
{
    public void Drive() { }
}

public class SpecialEngine : Engine
{
    public void Charge() { }
}

public class Car
{
    protected virtual Engine Engine { get; }
    public virtual void Move()
    {
        Engine.Drive();
    }
}

public class SpecialCar : Car
{
    protected override SpecialEngine Engine { get; }
    public override void Move()
    {
        Engine.Charge();
        base.Move();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Please add a note explaining that this is only supported by the dotnet core runtime instead of .NET

Answer (score 2):

I think a cleaner design would be to avoid having two fields in SpecialCar that could potentially reference two different Engine objects. Instead of declaring an Engine *field* in Car, declare an abstract Engine *property*, which is implemented by two Car subclasses:

```
public abstract class Car {
    protected abstract Engine Engine { get; }

    public virtual void Move() {
        this.Engine.Drive();
    }
}

public class RegularCar : Car {
    protected override Engine Engine { get; } = new Engine();
    // Or, without the auto-implemented property syntax:
    //   private Engine engine = new Engine();
    //   protected override Engine Engine => this.engine;
}

public class SpecialCar : Car {
    protected override SpecialEngine Engine { get; } = new SpecialEngine();
    // Or, without the auto-implemented property syntax:
    //   private SpecialEngine engine = new SpecialEngine();
    //   protected override SpecialEngine Engine => this.engine;
    // Note: Covariant return type requires C# 9.0 and .NET 5 or later.

    public override void Move() {
        this.Engine.Charge();
        base.Move();
    }
}
```

---

hatcyl posted a solution in which the `Car.Engine` property is `virtual` instead of `abstract`. I would personally not use this solution because SpecialCar winds up with both an Engine backing field (inherited from Car) and a SpecialEngine backing field. The Engine backing field is unused but can still be accessed from SpecialCar via `base.Engine`, which could return `null`, an Engine object, or a SpecialEngine object, depending on how the Car class initializes its Engine auto-implemented property.

Inheriting unnecessary state is a code smell that can be avoided by applying this general OOP design guideline: *Avoid deriving a concrete class from another concrete class. Instead, introduce an abstract, common base class of both concrete classes.* You can then move any state and behavior that's specific to a concrete class to that concrete class.